# Redshift join wildcard

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do a wildcard search based on the result set of a subquery in Redshift. For example, Table A has first names and Table B has names which could be Last Name, First Name or First Name, Last Name. I want to return rows from Table B based on matches to a subset of Table A. I found the Similar To operator, but that only seems to work when I can hard-code the terms I am searching for. Is there a way I can achieve something like

```
SELECT col1 FROM Table_A WHERE col1 SIMILAR TO '%(SELECT distinct col2 FROM Table_B)%'
```

in order to achieve

```
SELECT col1 FROM Table_A WHERE col1 LIKE '%something%' OR col1 LIKE '%something else%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select col1
from table_a a
where exists (
    select 1
    from table_b b
    where a.col1 similar to concat('%', b.col2, '%')
)
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I ended up implementing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up implementing after a recommendation from @GMB

```
CREATE TABLE test2 AS (
 SELECT 'a' as val
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'b' as val
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'c' as val
);
CREATE TABLE test3 as (
 SELECT 'apple' as name
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'pear' as name
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'plum' as name
);
SELECT * FROM test3
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 
 FROM test2 WHERE test3.name LIKE ('%'||val||'%')
)
```